# Unable to install handbrake on ubuntu server

Tags: 18.04, apt, software-installation, handbrake

I am trying to install handbrake on my ubuntu server but it gives error not found even if i have added apt repository source following: https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-releases

```
root@localhost:~# apt-get install handbrake-gtk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package handbrake-gtk
root@localhost:~# apt-get install handbrake-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package handbrake-cli
```

And on a different host i get this error :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
[sudo] password for rock64: 
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~stebbins/ubuntu/handbrake-releases'.
ERROR: '~stebbins' user or team does not exist.
```

How should i install handbrake ?

Comment: Did you add the required repository as described in the link ?

Comment: Ofcourse from the link I mentioned in opening post

Comment: You don't think that this error has any impact on your problem: `ERROR: '~stebbins' user or team does not exist.` ? That is, if you got the same error on the original machine.

Comment: This error only show up on second host

Comment: Have you ran `sudo apt update` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) then use [`handbrake` package name](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=handbrake&searchon=names)

Comment: no i get this message :

`$ sudo add-apt-repository "ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots universe"
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~stebbins/ubuntu/handbrake-snapshots universe'.
The user named '~stebbins' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/handbrake-snapshots universe'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'handbrake-git-snapshots':  HandBrake GIT Snapshots
 * 'handbrake-releases':  HandBrake Releases
 * 'handbrake-snapshots':  OBSOLETE: HandBrake Snapshots`

Comment: @Liso so many times